# Fat tailed continuous probability distribution list

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Hello I am working on a project and I need a list of fat-tailed continuous probability distributions from which I will choose the ones that will work for me.

What I am looking for is a list of probability distributions with fat tails, that is a larger than 0 excess kurtosis, and it's symmetric on both sides of the mean with 0 or little skew.

It should be like the normal distribution, except the distant values should not decay that quickly, I want the values to spread towards a larger number, even if the standard deviation set is small. Instead of looking like a bell it should look more like a hat or a flying saucer.

Comment: Which ones have you found yourself? Do you need the fourth moment (or indeed the first and second moments) to be finite?

Comment: @Henry I don't know, I have to test them all that is why I need a list of continuous distributions which look like the normal distirbution except with fat tails. I have checked the Cauchy and the Logistic distribution so far, something along those lines.

Comment: Std Cauchy [same as T(df=1)]  has such heavy tails that mean is not defined. (Dist;s T(2), T(3) also have heavy tails.) Laplace (double exponential) has such heavy tails that sample median is often better estimate of center than sample mean. See Wikipedia for more about each.

Comment: I think **Lévy's Stable Distribution** is what I was looking for, since it has an alpha and beta parameter with which I can customize the shape of the curve and study it's behavior further.